# Bandwidth shaping for an ipset using qdisc and tc

Tags: shell, sh, bandwidth, trafficshaping

I am trying to do bandwidth control for an ipset using [this tutorial](https://www.iplocation.net/traffic-control). I have modified it to get ipsetnames.

This is my bandwithshaing script.

```
TC=/sbin/tc
IF=wlan0             # Interface 
DNLD=1mbit          # DOWNLOAD Limit
UPLD=1mbit          # UPLOAD Limit 
IP1="myIPset1"     # Host IP
IP2="myIPset2"
U32="$TC filter add dev $IF protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32"

start() {

    $TC qdisc add dev $IF root handle 1: htb default 30
    $TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $DNLD
    $TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate $UPLD
    $U32 match iptables dst $IP flowid 1:1
    $U32 match iptables src $IP flowid 1:2

        #second chain
    $TC qdisc add dev $IF root handle 1: htb default 30
    $TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $DNLD
    $TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate $UPLD
    $U32 match iptables dst $IP1 flowid 1:1
    $U32 match iptables src $IP1 flowid 1:2
}

stop() {

    $TC qdisc del dev $IF root

}

restart() {

    stop
    sleep 1
    start
    }

show() {

    $TC -s qdisc ls dev $IF
    }
case "$1" in

  start)
        echo -n "Starting bandwidth shaping: "
    start
    echo "done"
    ;;

  stop)

    echo -n "Stopping bandwidth shaping: "
    stop
    echo "done"
    ;;

  restart)
        echo -n "Restarting bandwidth shaping: "
    restart
    echo "done"
    ;;
  show)
        echo "Bandwidth shaping status for $IF:\n"
    show
    echo ""
    ;;

  *)
        pwd=$(pwd)
    echo "Usage: $(/usr/bin/dirname $pwd)/tc.bash {start|stop|restart|show}"
    ;;

esac
exit 0
```

When I try to start bandwithshaping script, I am getting following output.
Starting bandwidth shaping: Illegal "match"

```
Illegal "match"
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Illegal "match"
Illegal "match"
done
```

This is not shaping the bandwidth. If I use an IP address, it works fine.

I am new for qdisc and tc, is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.